# using WHERE and AND clause with SQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to write the the select statement to fetch from the products table using the combination of the companyid and customerid, I am very sure I'm not doing it the right way, kindly help me to write the right sql to fetch using these parameters.

```
$customerid=$_SESSION['customersid'];
$companyid=$_SESSION['companyid'];

$test="SELECT producttype,quantity FROM product WHERE username= '" . mysql_real_escape_string($customerid) . "'" . 'AND'.mysql_real_escape_string($companyid) . "'" ;
```

Comment: `echo $test;` does it look correct?

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) speaks to best practices. If you're serious about using PHP as a development platform there are many [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

You must put the fieldname for the companyid in the query

```
$test="SELECT producttype,quantity FROM product WHERE username= '" . mysql_real_escape_string($customerid) . "'" . 'AND COMPANYID_FIELDNAME ='.mysql_real_escape_string($companyid) . "'" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is incorrect. Try the following:

```
 $customerid = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['customersid']);
 $companyid = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['companyid']);

 $test = "
          SELECT producttype,quantity 
          FROM product 
          WHERE username='$customerid' 
          AND company='$companyid'
         ";
```

Btw, you should be using `mysqli` and not `mysql` since it is deprecated.